# What is the use of the camera?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I found that if you type `/give @p camera`, it gives you a camera.
Is there a use for it?

Comment: Apparently you're playing with mods, so please list them. There is no camera in Vanilla Minecraft (except the imaginary one in your head).

Comment: @FabianRöling I think this question may be about [this camera](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Camera) from the education edition and the bedrock edition.

Comment: Hi cats, welcome to Arqade! Could you clarify what version of Minecraft you're using (specifically if it's Education edition or not), and if you're using any mods? Once we get that clarification, we can remove it from being on hold.

Comment: @bearb001 Then the tag is wrong. If people don't even correctly specify what game they're playing, the question can't be answered.